# Memory allocation when loading a really large image on Android

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I need to figure out much memory I can allocate without having an `OutOfMemoryError` when loading a bitmap. I decided to load a *really* large image from a file. Here is its URL: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/LARGE_elevation.jpg

The image size is 14 488 498 bytes (14,5 MB on disk). And here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "LargeBitmapLargeBitmap";

    private ActivityManager mActivityManager;
    private ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        findViewById(R.id.get_mem_info).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.load_bitmap).setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.get_mem_info:
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "maxMemory: " + rt.maxMemory());
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "freeMemory: " + rt.freeMemory());
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "totalMemory: " + rt.totalMemory());
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "mActivityManager.getMemoryClass(): " + mActivityManager.getMemoryClass());
                break;
            case R.id.load_bitmap:
                new ImageLoadingTask(mImageView).execute();
                break;
        }
    }

    // I don't handle the screen rotation here since it's a test app
    private static class ImageLoadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>  {

        private ImageView mImageView;

        ImageLoadingTask(ImageView imageView) {
            mImageView = imageView;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(final Void... params) {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator
                    + "LARGE_elevation.jpg";
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError error) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to load the large bitmap", error);
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled the code above and ran it on my Nexus 5. Then I pressed the `get_mem_info` button and got the following output:

```
05-02 12:07:35.872 28053-28053/com.sample V/LargeBitmapLargeBitmap: maxMemory: 201326592
05-02 12:07:35.872 28053-28053/com.sample V/LargeBitmapLargeBitmap: freeMemory: 4991056
05-02 12:07:35.872 28053-28053/com.sample V/LargeBitmapLargeBitmap: totalMemory: 20733248
05-02 12:07:35.873 28053-28053/com.sample V/LargeBitmapLargeBitmap: mActivityManager.getMemoryClass(): 192
```

which means that the heap memory available for my application is 192 MB. But when I pressed the `load_bitmap` button, the image wasn't loaded, and I got an `OutOfMemoryError`:

```
05-02 12:07:38.712 28053-29533/com.sample E/LargeBitmapLargeBitmap: Failed to load the large bitmap
                                                                    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 233280012 byte allocation with 10567360 free bytes and 176MB until OOM
                                                                        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:635)
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:611)
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:391)
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:417)
                                                                        at com.sample.MainActivity$ImageLoadingTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:70)
                                                                        at com.sample.MainActivity$ImageLoadingTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:55)
```

Why did that happen? Why did the system need to allocate 233280012 bytes (about 220MB)? The part "10567360 free bytes and 176MB until OOM" looks strange to me as well. Why do I see these numbers?

Comment: Di you read this https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @MuhammadBabar, yes. But actually my question is about those strange numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first,
14.5 MB is the size of the **JPEG** but not the size of your actual image.
Similarly, try to resave the image as png, you will see that size is increased by factors of 10, i.e. it might even reach 150 MB

One thing that you must keep in mind is that these images are **compressed** into JPEG or PNG.
But when these images are loaded into imageview or so, each **Bit** of the image is decompressed and occupies a memory in RAM.

So the actual size of your image is basically its resolution multiplied by 4 (A-R-G-B)

**EDIT - How to handle these images then?**
Firstly, use Glide (or Picasso) to load the images, instead of writing own AsyncTask for this.

**In Glide there is a method called `override(int width, int height)` which will resize the image while downloading**.
Ideally width and height should be the exact dimension of the ImageView (or any view), this will prevent the image from pixellating and also it will save the additional consumption of the memory. (you can always do minor calculations to retain image aspect ratio too)

Comment: First off, you were right about the size of the corresponding PNG. It's 116 965 828 bytes (117 MB on disk). I just saved the JPEG as a PNG file. Really a factor of 10. Second, if the size of the loaded image is calculated as it height multiplied by its width and then multiplied by 4, for my image the result is 10800 * 5400 * 4 = 233 280 000 bytes. It's almost what I saw in my log: Failed to allocate a 233280012 byte. Not sure, it may be a coincidence

Answer (score -2):

You should use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). Its a library endorsed by Google. It automatically handles all the memory management and also the image loading functionality.

Comment: Just for little clarification. Glide doesn't handle memory issues automatically. Little misuse of Glide can lead to enormous OOM issues. You have to design your app in such a way that Glide and other images work appropriately. And yea, you have to use Glide builder efficiently too.