# Saved image is larger than the image I picked from gallery

Tags: android, image

I picked image from the gallery using my android application and saved in Environment directory without doing any processing on it. The original image size was 1.4 Mb but new saved image size is more than 4 Mb. 
Code I used is as follows.

```
case REQUEST_CODE_FROM_GALLERY:
            String datastring1=data.getDataString();
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
                Log.e("..............",bitmap.getHeight()+","+bitmap.getWidth());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            storeImage(bitmap);

            break;

private boolean storeImage(Bitmap image) {
    File pictureFile = createDir(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
        return true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

private File createDir(int type) {
    File file;
    File filedir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "EffitientImageLoading");
    if (!filedir.exists()) {
        if (!filedir.mkdir())
            Toast.makeText(this, "Directory could not be created!! Try Again"
                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddmmyy_hhmmss").format(new Date());
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        file = new File(filedir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_" + timestamp + ".png");
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    currentphotopath = "file:" + file.getAbsolutePath();
    return file;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you change `Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100` to `Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10`? Smaller size, worst quality. In your case, the ratio seems to be 1:3 (1.4MB to 4.2 MB). Therefore, `Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 33` should do the trick. Also mind that JPEG uses LOSSY compression. Therefore, EACH TIME you save an image, its quality will become worser and worser.

Comment: Yes but 100 means saved image quality should be 100% i.e same as the size of image. But here image size is increasing than original. If i put 33 instead of 100 then quality loss will occure. @Rotwang

Comment: That's **totally wrong**. The image is decompressed in memory. So you are saving the 100% of the decompressed image, not of the original one.

Comment: `without doing any processing on it. `. Well you do. The original image is delivered to you as a bitmap. That was already the first processing. Then you convert bitmap to jpg. Thats the second processing.

Comment: Okay you mean when I capture image from camera it is first compressed then saved in the device? and when I retrieve, the decompressed image is returned. right?

Comment: Depending on how you initialise the camera app the camera app will save the image as jpg file or deliver you as extra a tumbnail in bitmap format. It is pretty unclear what you are doing and why you would request a bitmap from the media store.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43734674/5471104) and in your program you are saving file as png despite compressing it as jpeg. use file extension of jpeg and the size will further get reduced

Comment: @greenapps as I have told I am not capturing image but picking it from gallery.

Comment: Sorry. If you select an image from the gallery -how? Which intent?- then you should not invoke the mediastore to retrieve a bitmap from it. And you should not use a bitmap in any way if you simply want to copy the image. Very bad idea to use a bitmap while copying.

Comment: I used Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*"); to invoke gallery.

Comment: greenapps actually I am learning image handeling. Thats why I am doing just experiments to learn new things about it. can u give me any idea from where I can learn more about it. any website or any another source youtube tutorial etc.

Comment: I think its important also to know how to copy a file from an obtained uri or content scheme. So finish this question first. Has not much to do with image handling indeed. Just basic stuff. A a file copy.

Comment: @MohammedAtif I did it but no any effect. just file extention is changed. Size is exactly same as previous.

Comment: thanks everyone for ur replies and support.

Answer (score 1):

**Actually you are using `.PNG` file format to save image but its a lossless format it can't compress the size of image. i am putting your code with some corrections, use it and revert me if you found any changes in size of image.**

```
case REQUEST_CODE_FROM_GALLERY:
            String datastring1=data.getDataString();
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
                Log.e("..............",bitmap.getHeight()+","+bitmap.getWidth());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            storeImage(bitmap);

            break;

private boolean storeImage(Bitmap image) {
    File pictureFile = createDir(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
        return true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

private File createDir(int type) {
    File file;
    File filedir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "EffitientImageLoading");
    if (!filedir.exists()) {
        if (!filedir.mkdir())
            Toast.makeText(this, "Directory could not be created!! Try Again"
                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddmmyy_hhmmss").format(new Date());
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        file = new File(filedir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_" + timestamp + ".JPEG");
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    currentphotopath = "file:" + file.getAbsolutePath();
    return file;
}
```

Comment: this reduced the size of image to about 30%. but I want to know what 100 means. Isn't it mean that original image.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy the picked image then open an input stream for the obtained uri and a file output stream for your file path. Then read from input stream in a loop chuncks and write them to the file output stream. A normal copy.

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStrea(data.getData());

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStrea(path);
```

Comment: @deepakbajpay just read this answer, this is the only way you should follow

Answer (score 0):

well you can reduce the quality of the image --

```
 image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, fileOutputStream);
```

this save your images with 60% quality.

saving the decompressed image is adding up the space.